# Plugin failed error while opening xcode

Tags: xcode

I just downloaded and installed xcode from app store. But when i open it I get Plugin failed error. I tried searching on web about this problem. Found that it was some python related issues. SO i tried installing different versions of python, but still no success.

I dont know where is the actual problem... So i need ur help in troubleshooting this problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanx in advance....